# How to find video and audio stream data in MP4 files

Tags: audio, video, mp4, codec

Is there any way to find the type of stream data in the mdat of a MP4 file?
In other word how can i separate video and audio units of file?
I suppose that we don't have any headers or footers (only mdat is available).